# Mongoose select function with aggregate or near functions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a model named Rest with lots of columns and i only want to fetch few among them while applying near operator on that Rest model. this is my code

```
Rest
    .select('rest_status rest_address rest_name rest_contact rest_photo rest_menu rest_avg_rating')
    .aggregate().near({
      near:[parseFloat(req.body.lng),parseFloat(req.body.lat)],
      maxDistance:100000,
      spherical:true,
      distanceField:"dist.calculated"
    })
    .then(rests =>{
      // const response=[];
      //     for(const rest of rests){
      //       console.log(rest);
      //       response.push(rest);
      //     }
      res.send({rests,response_status});
    }).catch(err => res.send(err));
```

when i try like this . i get an error that select is not a function. i tried changing select position like below aggregate and near but it didnt work. I'm new to this mongoose,please tell me if there is any function or way around to fetch limited columns from my model.
i forgot to mention both near and select and working fine when other one is not used and also please help me with changing the data obtain from model

Comment: hey, have added an answer, have a look , i have added one answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this below:

```
Rest.aggregate([
  {
    $geoNear: {
      near: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [parseFloat(req.body.lng), parseFloat(req.body.lat)]
      },
      maxDistance: 100000,
      spherical: true,

      distanceField: "dist.calculated"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      rest_status: 1,
      rest_address: 1,
      rest_name: 1,
      rest_contact: 1,
      rest_photo: 1,
      rest_menu: 1,
      rest_avg_rating: 1
    }
  }
  //even you can add limit skip below , if u need
  ,{$limit:<Number>},
  { $skip: <Number>}
]
//depends on your mongo version you may need to set cursor as well.
,
{ cursor: { batchSize: <Number or keep 0> } }
)
  .then()
  .catch();
```

**Note: before execute the query make sure you have added `2dsphere` index to your `dist.calculated` field**

in case of aggegate [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) is used for what you want to do with `.select`

instead of using `.near()` i have used [`$geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/).

if you want to use limit skip you can follow the example, other wise can remove that.

you also can add `distanceMultiplier` and `includeLocs` field depends on your requirement.

in the above, depends on the mongoDB version you may need to use `cursor` in aggregate.
if not you can go aheadwithout using the `cursor`.

Hope this helps.

if you still get any error, please comment.

Comment: sorry for this late reply and thanks for the answer. how can I filter the result basing on a field [ex: rest_status :  "available"] along with current config . i tried using find but aggregate and find are clashing with each other and one last request could you suggest me a doc or some site to understand this functions, i'm currently using only mongoose functions[find,near etc]  which have limited functionalites

Comment: well, in that case you can also add `$match`, in which yu can pass conditions.
have a look here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/

Comment: great, @gouthamreddy if it helped you, and think its may be the right answer, you also can give a upvote. :)

Comment: i did but StackOverflow says my reputation isn't enough to show  upvotes given by me